# how to get total results in laravel pagination?

Tags: laravel, api, collections, pagination

I have collection `$data=$qwery->paginate();`

Further in the loop, I send an api request for each element and receive data, which I use with `setAttribute` to add to the current element of the collection.
In my blade file, I display the information in the form of a table. The last row of the table should contain the total amount of the field that we added using the api request for all elements on all pages. Can I get all collections of all pages in the controller and then calculate the amount using the standard collection method? I tried to use get() instead of pagination, but the request is taking too long, due to API. I can calculate the amount I need for the current page. But how can I find out the amount for all pages at once? I do not ask for a ready-made solution, just your ideas

Answer (score 3):

Use `$data->total()` to get the total number of items in your paginated results.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods